# Can I get site Usage in Sharepoint online using CSOM?

Tags: client-object-model, site-usage

I want to get the "Site Usage Report" on a Sharepoint Online site using C#. How can I do it? This [link](https://sharepointmaven.com/6-ways-check-sharepoint-usage-reports/) provides solutions to get these details but I want to do it programatically using C# (CSOM).

Another [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245743/how-to-generate-the-site-usage-report-using-powershell-or-csom-code) along the similar lines was asked in the past, but I believe it wasn't answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code retrives the Usage Info but sadly, the Hits and Visits shows 0 because of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16050/values-in-spsite-usageinfo-are-always-zero) reason.

```
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site, s => s.Usage);
                try
                {
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    UsageInfo usageInfo = clientContext.Site.Usage;
                    usageData = "No. of hits: " + Convert.ToString("" + usageInfo.Hits) + "; ";
                    usageData += "No. of visits: " + Convert.ToString("" + usageInfo.Visits) + "; ";
                    usageData += "Storage: " + Convert.ToString("" + usageInfo.Storage) + "; ";
                    usageData += "Storage Percentage Used: " + Convert.ToString("" + usageInfo.StoragePercentageUsed) + "; ";

                    var bytes = usageInfo.Storage;
                    Debug.Print("UsageData " + usageData);
                    Debug.Print("Bytes " + bytes);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. To access the Site Usage info, you must have a sharepoint admin. You must load site.Usage property before accessing it.

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("siteUrl"))
            {
                var userName = "userName";
                var password = "password";

                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

                ctx.Load(ctx.Site, s => s.Usage);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                UsageInfo usageInfo = ctx.Site.Usage;

                Console.WriteLine("Storage Usage: " + usageInfo.Storage.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```